# find $\bar{E}$ and $E^{\circ}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $E \subset(0,+\infty), E \neq \varnothing$. such that $x / 2 \in E$ and $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \in$ $E$ for any $x, y \in E$, find $\bar{E}$ and $E^{\circ}$ . (with euclidean distance)

it is clear that $|E|=\infty$ also since  $E \neq \varnothing$ so we have $x_{0} \in E$ then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\frac{1}{2^nx_{0}} \in E$.

Comment: I am sorry but prove or find?

Comment: The closure is $[0,\infty)$ but I am not sure about the interior.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . I think $E$ is countable so interioir is empty.

Comment: @1200785626 $E=(0,\infty)$ satisfies the hypothesis and the interior is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The interior of $E$ cannot be determined by the given conditions. Consider the following examples:

1. $E=\{\frac {\sqrt n} {2^{m}}: n,m \in \mathbb N\}$
2. $E=(0,\infty)$.

In both case the given conditions hold. The interior in the first case is empty and it is $(0,\infty)$ in the second.

To show that the closure is $[0, \infty)$ note that $\sqrt 2 x=\sqrt {x^{2}+x^{2}} \in E$ for any $x \in E$. Now use induction to show that $\sqrt n x\in E$ for any $x \in E$. Combined with your observation we see that $\frac {\sqrt n} {2^{m}} x \in E$ for any $x \in E$. Hence, $\frac {n} {2^{m}} x \in E$ for any $x \in E$. Since numbers of the form $\frac {n} {2^{m}}$ are dense in $(0,\infty)$ it follows that $\overline E=[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E \neq \emptyset$, consider $\bar x \in E$. Then, since $x/2 \in E \;\forall x \in E$, we have a sequence of points of $E$ converging to $0$. Consider $\bar x / 2$. Since $\sqrt{\bar x^2 + (\bar x/2)^2} \in E$, we have $\sqrt{5}/2 \; \bar x \;(> \bar x) \in E$. We can then construct a sequence that goes to $\infty$.

It should then not be difficult to show that the closure is $[0, \infty)$.

For the interior, I think it depends on $E$, and it can be or empty or $(0,\infty)$.
In the first case, $E$ can be "generated" by a countable set of initial points, by a countable set of operations.
In the second case, you just need a point and a small neighborhood of it.

However this is just a quick thought, hoping it could help, but should work.